# Filtering objects based on two attributes being the same

Tags: python, django

With regards to the below model, how could I filter through existing objects so that I find only objects where 'Name' contains a certain word, for example, "Green" but also where the vendor of the object may contain "Green"? I am of course referring to the value (assuming same type although in this example I am using char and text field).

```
class Hat(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = False)
    Size = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 11), range(1, 11))), unique=False)
    Vendor = models.TextField(max_length=255, unique = False)
```

```
List = [for Hat in Hat.objects.filter(Name__contain="Green")]
```

Comment: So the two fields should contain `Green`, or one is sufficient? The search should be case sensitive?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem one is sufficient. If the object has either green in name or vendor, then I want it in my list. But I know to do this I must check both an object's name and vendor.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in this case, it does not matter if capitals are used or not (so no, not case senstive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Hat.objects.filter(Name__contains='Green', Vendor__contains='Green', _connector=Q.OR)
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `vendor` instead of <s>`Vendor`</s>.

---

> **Note**: For case-*in*sensitive matches, you can use the [**`__icontains`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains). Case insitive matching is *not* equivalent to converting the two operands to lowercase: case insensitive matching is more sophisticated since some characters have no uppercase or lowercase variant, and there are certain rules when two characters are considered the same in an case-insenstive manner.